# java find the location of a .jar regardless of where user puts it

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, directory, location

In my program I made a saving and loading system for text files. The Save function works perfectly as intended but the Load gives a NullPointerException.

Here's the load function

```
String path = "C:\\Levels\\File.txt";
LevelHandler.loadLevel(path);
```

Here's the loadLevel function

```
public static void loadLevel(String file){
    String level = LevelLoader.loadFileAsString(file);
    //other, unimportant, code
}
```

And here's the loadFileAsString function

```
    public static String loadFileAsString(String file){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream in = LevelLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It's failing because it's looking for the file in the class folder regardless of what directory I pass in. How can I get the location of the .jar regardless of where the user places it on their computer?

Comment: Did I understand correctly? You always have absolute path to file, right?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim no I just used that to avoid going into the input and how it stitches the path string together

Answer (score 0):

you can get the .jar related location using **./** 
./ provides related path of your jar

Comment: so would it be like this? String path = "./File.txt";

Comment: yes, ./abc.txt means abc.txt files in same folder where your jar file present.

Comment: it still does not work. I tried ./jarname/levels/File.txt but that doesnt work either. Is there a way to access folders within the jar?

Answer (score 0):

The fix I came up with was to remove the InputStreamreader

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

This will be able to read files from any specified location on the computer, but still not from inside the jar. However it works perfectly fine with pretty much any other specified location.